# what is the use of adding triple dot in array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the use of adding triple dots in an array in javascript?

my code sample is:

```
let array = [newArray]
```

and

```
let array = [...newArray]*
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding triple dots on an array is called spread syntax

By using it like this newArray = [...existingArray], we spread the existingArray into newArray
so newArray has all the items of existingArray now.

Common use case of this syntax is to add new items into a new array with the existing items from another array

```
const oldArr = [2,3,4];
const newArr = [1,...oldArr]; //newArr = [1,2,3,4]

//If you put it like this..
const oldArr = [2,3,4];
const newArr = [oldArr]; //newArr = [[2,3,4]]
```

See this for more info :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax